# Angular js autocomplete typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to implement angular js typeahead directive for searching cities based on a particular country. Both should be autocomplete dropdowns. 
That is when I type in the country text box it should show me suggestions of countries in the dropdown for the keyword i type. 
When i type in city text box it should show me suggestions of cities related to only the selected country.
I have implemented the typeahead feature only for 1 textbox.
Now i need to search cities based on a selected country.

for example, if my json is as follows

```
$scope.data = [{
        countries: [{
                id: 1,
        name: country1
            }, 
        {
                id: 2,
        name: country2
                }, 
        {
                id: 3,
        name: country3
            }]
    cities: [{
            id: 1,
            city_name: 'city1'
        country_id: 1
        }, {
            id: 2,
            city_name: 'city2'
        country_id: 2
        }, {
            id: 3,
            city_name: 'city3'
        country_id: 2
        }, {
            id: 4,
            city_name: 'city4'
        country_id: 3
        }],


    }];
```

and if i have selected country2 in first text box then in the second text box it should display only city2 and city3 since they belong to country2

Comment: Well, if you already implemented one dropdown, the cities dropdown should be the same logic except that you'll use the previous dropdown (ngModel) as a parameter to filter the cities. Your question is not very clear by the way.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've made an edit to explain exactly what i want. i want to know how do i exactly filter the cities based on the country parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter.

#### adding filter syntax to html

```
<input ng-model="selectedCtry" 
    typeahead="ctry as ctry.name for ctry in data.countries"/>

<input ng-model="selectedCity" 
    typeahead="city as city.name for city in data.cities | filter:{ country_id: selectedCountry.id }"/>
```

example - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/jWyXeL?editors=101

Answer (score -1):

In country textbox make a call to server on blur and pass country, or country ID; and get list of city according to country